# php5 sqlite3 result and free

Tags: php, sqlite

I am using php5 and now sqite3.

I don't know how free result. The following code

```
$query = "SELECT ...;";
$result = $GLOBALS['sqlite']->query($query);
$row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
$result->free();
```

ends with Error `UNDEFINED METHOD`. What am I doing wrong?

And finally, I want to ask if it is faster to call `free()` or never free the result?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer turned out to be `$result->finalize();`